# How to pattern match on union constructors in `for .. in`

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

In Haskell, if I have a list of union typed values like this:

```hs
example :: [Either Int Char]
example = [Left 3, Right 'b', Left 6, Left 9, Right 'c']
```

I can use a little "trick" to extract all the results matching some specific pattern:

```hs
lefts :: [Int]
lefts = [l | Left l <- example]
```

However, if I try to translate this to F#, I get an error:

```
let lefts = [for Choice1Of2 l in example -> l]
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. (...)
```

This makes a lot of sense (it might even be better behavior than silently ignoring `Right` values like Haskell does!), but **in F#, is there some convenient way to extract (and match on) all values matching a certain pattern in a list/sequence**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In F# if you don't match against all cases you will get a warn, in all scenarios.

So you can write the match with both cases inside the expression, but for your example rather than comprehensions I would use the function `List.choose`:

```
let example = [Choice2Of2 3; Choice1Of2 'b'; Choice2Of2 6; Choice2Of2 9; Choice1Of2 'c']
List.choose (function (Choice1Of2 x) -> Some x | _ -> None) example
// val it : char list = ['b'; 'c']
```

This function is handy for those cases.

Answer (score 12):

I think the closest thing you can do using F# list expressions is something like this:

```
let lefts example = 
  [ for e in example do
      match e with Choice1Of2 l -> yield l | _ -> () ]
```

If I understand the Haskell code correctly, the part after `|` is used not just as an extractor, but also as a filter - implicitly skipping over all things that do not match the pattern.

F# does not have the same kind of concept in list expressions, so you have to be more verbose. Here, we just iterate over *all* items using `for` and then we explicitly use `yield` to produce a new value for each `Choice1Of2` in the source list (and we just skip over anything else).

Depending on what you're doing, using `List.choose` (as mentioned in Gustavo's answer) might be easier. But the above is probably closest you can get to the Haskell's *comprehension* syntax.